# Missing redirect url. in forgotPassword in Devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-api

In devise_token_auth signup and signin are working fine.But passwords reset giving error.

```
Missing redirect url.
```

It gives error in Password_controller.rb on these lines

```
@redirect_url = params[:redirect_url]

  # fall back to default value if provided
  @redirect_url ||= DeviseTokenAuth.default_password_reset_url

  unless @redirect_url
    return render_create_error_missing_redirect_url
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't provide the `default_password_reset_url` on the initializer. Under config/initializers/devise_token_auth.rb try the following:

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.default_password_reset_url = <your_url>
end
```

You can see the options available here: https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/config/initialization

Comment: Can you help me which url should I give there?

Comment: maybe just with `root_url`. Is the url the system will redirect_to after a successful password reset

Comment: getting this error inspite of having this initializer and passing redirect_url as well to /api/v1/auth/password

Comment: @vipin8169 you need to restart `rails server` when updating your initialisers

Comment: Choose **<your_url>** depending on what `redirect_url` you would like to have as part of the confirmation link: `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/password/edit?config=default&redirect_url=<YOUR_URL>&reset_password_token=EyLxn95R3zo-bPs1txdY`